# Custom field sorting based on an int

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a list of database fields:

```
id    order    title
1     3        This is a post
2     1        This is another post
3     2        This is also a post
4     4        This is still a post
```

And I want change the order of these based on *order*.
If I set order on id #1 to 2 I want order on id #3 to be set to 3.
If I set order on id #4 to 1 I want order on id #1 to be 4, order on id #2 to be 2, order on id #3 to be 3 etc. etc.

How can I do this? I think it should be quite simple but I can't figure it out.
I have searched but I don't know what to search for...

Comment: unable to understand the question!!!!! which ids you r referring to `id` or `order`

Comment: the process you trying to achieve is not possible as there is no pattern specified according to your question. if it was a simple swap it can be done but this cant be done by using simple php, This requires a very high level of understanding with Artificial intelligence

Comment: @VIPINJAIN: If only I could downvote comments.

Comment: @eggyal : Can you find a pattern in the question????

Comment: @VIPINJAIN: Yes.  See my answer below.

Comment: @eggyal : no bud, your answer is wrong. and i found the pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in SQL with two `UPDATE` statements:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT order FROM t WHERE order BETWEEN $new_order AND $old_order FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE t SET order = order + 1  WHERE order BETWEEN $new_order AND $old_order;
UPDATE t SET order = $new_order WHERE id = $id;

COMMIT;
```

I have locked the table during these updates to prevent concurrency issues (however, note that transactions/locks are only applicable to InnoDB tables).

Comment: Like this? `LOCK TABLES posts WRITE`

Comment: @Patrik: I've shown a lock (using [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)) in my updated answer.  Note that only InnoDB tables can be locked.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find the `$other_row`, the one that has the `order` value you want to reuse. Then change each row’s value.

```
$id_to_set = 1;
$order_to_set = 2;

// Find the order that will need to be swapped
$result = mysql_query("select order from xxx where id = $id_to_set");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
// Find the other row that will be modified
$result = mysql_query("select id from xxx where order = $order_to_set");
$other_row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// Do the actual swapping
mysql_query("update xxxx set order = $order_to_set where id = $id_to_set");
mysql_query("update xxxx set order = " . $row['order'] . " where id = " . $other_row['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways :
read SQL doc and use the ORDER BY close in your query

read PHP doc and use usort function